# why only height is adjustable of parent div if child div is resizeable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new in html development . I sharing my simple code which have two div . one div is parent div and second div is it's child div .So now problem is that when I resizing child div only height is adjustable but when I resizing chid div to right side width of parent div not adjustable but I want it . So please anyone help me . following is my code :

```html
<div style='border:1px solid;padding:20px;width:auto;height:auto;'>
  <div style="resize: both;overflow:auto;border:1px solid;width:500px;height:200px;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use `display: inline-block`.

```css
.first {
  border:1px solid;
  padding:20px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.second {
  resize: both;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
 <div class="first">
 
<div class="second"></div>
  <br>
<div class="second"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you that is working but if there have multiple parent div  and more than one child div of same parent which described in code .